# How to unsupport iPad properly in iTunes

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

We have an app on AppStore for almost 3 years, and we've set Deployment Device Info of this app as "iPhone" (not "Universal").
Earlier it seems iPad users could download our app and used it by enlarging the screen. 
Now our uses reported they cannot download our app. (The guy who reported uses iPad Air + iOS7.1.1)
[image]

So, my first question is..
Is this new AppStore regulation that does't allow iPad users to download apps with "iPhone" set as deployment device target ?

We are fine if it's the regulation, but more confusing is when seeing the app in AppStore with Mac, we still see our app is compatible with iPads. 
So my second question is..
From what info AppStore shows this compatibility information ?

[image]

Our aim is not to confuse users, so we want to go either way - tell users we are completely unsupporting iPads, or tell them you can download the app anyway.

Comment: I just downloaded one of my own apps to my iPad Mini Retina that was iPhone only. (I had already purchased it, but it downloaded fine with out an issue).

Comment: I just installed your app on my iPad mini retina with 7.1.1 with no issue. Perhaps your user has some restrictions or policy in place?  Does your app mandate location capabilities?  Perhaps if these are restricted by policy the user can't install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That device list suggests that you require cellular access. Does the user in question have a wifi only iPad? The dialogue would be shown if the app required capabilities that the device did not have.

There is no change to the App Store policy - iPad users can still download iPhone apps, and it's pretty clear in the store that you're not getting an iPad-native version.

To answer your second question, the information shown in the App Store comes from what is set in your info plist- the minimum targeted version of iOS, and then device capabilities. Device capabilities are explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1397/_index.html).

Comment: sounds like the right answer, the dialog shown says 'this iPad' not iPads generally. It's likely that there is something set in the device requirements in the info-plist file like, as suggested, cellular access or location services with GPS or Bluetooth LE.

Comment: @jrturton
Thank you so much for your advice, we are asking that user through CS team now to check his iPad is wifi-only (probably it is).